# obtain values of a vector java reflection

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I'm doing work completed in college, I'm working with reflection in java I have a little doubt about how to obtain the value of a vector, but also how to get the fields of an object built.

Comment: Staff?  Poor translation, I hope...

Comment: Please provide a specific example of a problem you are having, including what code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the [Java reflection tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) for more information about reflection

I do not know what you mean by 'obtaining the value of a vector', but retrieving the fields of an object is rather simple. For example

```
Object anObject = ....;
Field[] fields = anObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
//to obtain the value of the field for anObject
Field field = fields[0];
field.setAccessible( true );//since declared fields also returns private fields
Object fieldValue = field.get( anObject );
```